# Is there a way to update a trained machine learning model in Weka while making predictions for new data (Java)?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, raspberry-pi3, machine-learning-model

I have implemented  classification algorithms using machine learning using Weka Java. I would like to deploy the trained model on RasberryPi to test.. I want then the trained model get updated every time when it receive the new data and make predictions?? Is there a way to do that with weka Java ?? Could you share your thoughts how to proceed??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm bored so I'll try to help since this is a tough and common problem as more and more people integrate machine learning into their normal dev processes...even though this is a bit broad for SO.

I would ask yourself a few questions:

1. How often does this particular model need to be refreshed in order to maintain relevancy to the task it is performing for you?

Typically, retraining a classification model when every new row of data is written to the place you get training data from would be insane. So I would think about that.

2. How long does it take to build the model, and how long WILL it take to build it as more and more training data piles up?
3. Where do you keep your training data, and how do you label it so fast that you would be able to retrain the model every time you get new data? Or is it not a typical supervised classification model?

I ask this because, from what i've done, the data you train with will go into some kind of database, or file system or whatever, and if the Java code you use to build the model reads from a standard location on disk or a DB, rebuilding the model isn't all that hard...it can be a CRON job or a jenkins job or whatever to rebuild the model (read data, build model, write model to disk, deploy model). You'll want the process that uses the model to be able to read it from configuration, and you'll want the code that builds the model to be able to configure the location of the training data corpus. a simple Java properties file might suffice for this piece.

4. Will you need to reprocess all your data every time you build a new model? This is also a common problem, sometimes solved by tagging each classified item with the *version* of the model that you used to classify it. In this case, you can set up a "reprocessing pipeline" that looks for old classification results and pumps them through the new model. This opens up a can of worms depending on how you do you data (dedupe strategy, history keeping, etc) so think about that one.

I don't know anything at all about Raspberry pi, but that part doesn't seem relevant since this is really a software architecture problem. One way I've done the automagic deployment piece is to use Jenkins and something like PUPPET to push/pull the model to machine it will be used on. In my past I've put NLP models on to a Hadoop and Storm cluster with puppet and the java code picks them up from a static NFS mount that is on all nodes. etc.....

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MOA](https://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/overview/) (Massive Online Analysis) package from the Weka developers. It does basically what you want- updating the training model incrementally (= "online").

MOA is (freely) available as a standalone product, or as an extension to Weka, as far as I remember.